# directional derivative for a composite function

Tags: real-analysis

G $\in$ $C^1(\Bbb R^2)$ with $G(1,1)-1\ge G(x,1)-x$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ and $G(1,1)\le G(1,y)$ for all $y \in \Bbb R$

$F(s,t)=G(2st-s+1,2st+s+1)$. I've to found the directional derivative of F in $(0,0)$

respect the unit vector $v=(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$

G restricted to $(x,1)$ has a minimum in $1$?

$G(x,1)-G(1,1)\le x-1$ so for $lim _{x->1^+}$ ${G(x,1)-G(1,1)}\over {x-1}$$ \le0$ and $lim _{x->1^-}$ ${G(x,1)-G(1,1)}\over {x-1}$$ \ge0$ and so the directional derivative don't exist?